# How to create/submit a portal in iOS

Tags: ingress

iOS version of the game has recently released. I faced the idea to submit a new portal in an area where theres is a low amount of them, and all the tutorial that I found consist in "sharing" the image with `NIA Service Ops` or press and hold on the map inside the app to make appear a menu that contains `New Portal` option.

[image: Create Portal option from Android App]

But this must be only for Android version of the app. I'm level 1 and maybe this could affect, however I didn't read anything specifying that there is a minimum level.

So the question is... can a new portal be submitted from iOS?

Comment: What happens when you try to open that menu?

Comment: @bunyaCloven It shows the first two options only, without the **New Portal** option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New release of ingress for iOS allows portal submissions as of 26th August 2014

Answer (score 9):

According to [Niantic](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808254?hl=en), you cannot.

You can optionally just take pictures and wait for its implementation.

> [image]

Comment: I added a picture (because the information in the link may change), hope you don't mind

Comment: Can portals be submitted through the web app?

Comment: @SysDragon What Web app? Do you mean ingress.com/intel? No.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs Looks like they plan to activate it: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/179332/43105

Answer (score 1):

It looks that they are going to allow portal submissions through the web:

> According to NiaOps (we met with them last friday for danish cross-faction meet up) the submission of portals might be opened up again via web, because the iOS 7 framework doesn't give the same access as android, for geo info. [Jul 23, 2014]

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/2aq6w3/ios_users_cant_submit_new_portals/

Comment: Fingers crossed. I've got at least 10 portals to submit.