# How do I add a Pokestop to my area?

Tags: pokemon-go

How do I add a Pokestop to an area that has none? It is an area where there are tons of businesses but unless I drive about a mile from my work area there are no Pokestops.

I want to add one since we have 1000's of people in the work area, a lot of them play Pokemon Go, and we all can't leave work to drive a mile away to get to a Pokestop area.

Plus it would be nice to be able to capture Pokemon on our breaks.

Comment: Was just going to comment and answer those same things - my fast fingers gotta git gud

Comment: This should be reopened. It's not a duplicate of the linked question. "How are they chosen" is different from "How do you add?". Additionally they have indeed added the ability to request PokeStops/Gyms.

https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319928

Comment: If we were to do things properly, we'd open this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273875/how-can-i-turn-my-house-into-a-pokestop and mark this one as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create/submit a portal in iOS](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177152/how-to-create-submit-a-portal-in-ios)

Comment: @aytimothy how is this a duplicate when it is for a different game and has different answers?

Comment: @GodEmperorDune [tag:pokemon-go] uses the same location data as [tag:ingress] as stated [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/274715/75275) (scroll down). However, it seems that the answer here is more up-to-date.

Comment: @aytimothy "originally ported over" is different from "uses". Without a post from ingress, we don't know if they datasets are still shared or were just copied over and are now independent, so new pokestops don't become ingress portals or vice versa.

Answer (score 18):

PokeStops were originally ported over from Niantic's old game, Ingress. For a few days, you could request to have a PokeStop added [by opening a support ticket with Niantic](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319928). As of now, the page for requesting a PokeStop is closed, and it is unknown if it will ever open again.

Answer (score 16):

[Niantic](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221968408-Reporting-Pok%C3%A9Stop-or-Gym-Issues) is no longer accepting applications for new PokeStops.

Quote from Website that is linked:

> Please note, we are currently not accepting submissions for new PokéStops or Gyms.

Comment: The Niantic link is dead

Answer (score 8):

It appears it's now possible to submit PokéStop nominations upon reaching **level 37**. The guidelines for such can be found [on Niantic's support site](https://niantic.helpshift.com/hc/en/6-pokemon-go/faq/41-submitting-a-pokestop-nomination/), but essentially:

1. First, go to an object or location that you think would make a good PokéStop.
2. Tap the Main Menu button.
3. Tap the Settings button.
4. Tap the New PokéStop button to start the nomination process.
5. Tap the location of the Pokéstop on the map.
6. Take a photo of the object, then the object and its surroundings.
7. Add a title/description for the object.

Ensure your PokéStop is a good enough landmark ([see link for guidelines](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/wayfarer/?p=web&s=wayspot-eligibility)) for it to be included, and you're highly likely to be marked as eligible.