# Can I create a PokeStop in an open playground?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a rural area, recently touched level 38 in Pokemon Go somehow.

My house is in the outer side of the main city , and our whole city has only 4 pokestops and 2 gyms, that too almost 2 Miles away from my home in the center of the city , so it's quite hard for me to get there everytime for gym battles, raids and pokestop items so, after reaching level 38 i want to increase the number of pokestop.

There is an open playground in our area which is accessible for the public and also very great spot for sports like,

Football training, Football Matches, Cricket Matches and others.

Great for exercising and yoga

Great spot for morning and evening walks, driving practicing too.

Features of the playground.

1. Always crowdy except noon and night time.
2. Nice for sports and others.
3. Very safe for pedestrians.
4. Always accessible as there is no boundary

But,the playground does not have any signboard , plaque , statue , unique art or something like that, but , it's sure that the playground is almost always crowdy.

So, is it eligible for a pokestop submission? , Thank You.

Edit:

As no Interesting bench or art exists except goal posts, will the photo of goal post make an eligible pokestop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a Pokestop to my area?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274713/how-do-i-add-a-pokestop-to-my-area)

Comment: No, i am asking whether an open playground can be a good pokestop or not . The playground is well crowdy everytime and it's also safe for pedestrians, but the playground doesn't have any statues, plaques , historical stories etc.

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar One of the possible eligibility requirements for a pokéstop is that it's a "great place for exercise and sports", like parks.

Comment: Is there nothing interesting at all there? Even a memorial bench or a particularly impressive climbing frame would help the nomination.

Comment: @Studoku, none but goal post rods

Comment: Nzall , i know this but, will only pictures of goalposts make a successful nomination?

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar We are not affliliated with Niantic, nor are we psychic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible for us to know whether your park is suitable for a PokéStop without seeing the park itself.

However, considering you're level 38, you're allowed to suggest new PokéStops that the community may vote on. The procedure is explained in https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=in-game-locations&f=submitting-a-pokestop-nomination&l=en&p=web, but it effectively boils down to:

1. First, go to an object or location that you think would make a good
   PokéStop.
2. Tap the Main Menu  button.
3. Tap the Settings button.
4. Tap the New PokéStop button to start the nomination.
5. Follow the instructions in the app.

I checked the WaySpot criteria guide and it appears your location likely is eligible. I'd suggest you try and submit it.